# Compare two logs line by line and show differences and if the order of words from a line are not the same

Tags: shell-script, awk, grep, diff, file-comparison

I Don't need a tool I need an implemetation/alghorithm :)
I need to make a shellscript because I can't install anything on the server

**f2.txt**

```
She has 123 apples
George 18 years is old
Florin it's leaving
Michael it's not here
Peter is smiling
```

**f1.txt**

```
She has 132 apples
George is 18 years old
Michael it's not here
Peter is smiling
He is sleeping
```

**Desired output:**

```
diff is at:
line 1 : 123 instead of 132
line 2 : 18 years is instead of is 18 years
lines missing:
He is sleeping
lines added:
line 3: Florin it's leaving
```

Answer (score 3):

Not exactly the format you're asking for, but `wdiff` is probably your best bet:

```
$ wdiff f1.txt f2.txt
She has [-132-] {+123+} apples
George [-is-] 18 years {+is+} old
{+Florin it's leaving+}
Michael it's not here
Peter is smiling
[-He is sleeping-]
```

Comment: sdiff also provides an alternative, showing differences side by side.

Comment: it's a great tool but I can't install anything on the server so I have to implement it manually

Comment: @StoianGeorge, presumably, you'll still have to write a script for that. In what way is that different from copying a `wdiff` executable?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas it's not different. I have to write the algorithm of wdiff